# Почему сетевой троллинг так назван?

Tags: этимология, лексика, жаргон

1) **О сетевом троллинге**

Слово ***троллинг*** указано в словаре с пометкой *жарг*. (предположительно оно стало использоваться с 1996 года).

В наиболее общем виде это явление характеризуется как  **размещение на  ресурсах провокационных сообщений** для нагнетания конфликтной обстановки, при этом тролль пытается представить себя **типичным пользователем**, который разделяет общие интересы и проблемы сообщества.

**Для чего, к примеру,  тролли любят злить людей в сети?** Это желание перевести познавательную и умную беседу в совершенную бессмыслицу; или это желание на некоторое время обрушить форум или сайт; или стремление обратить на свою личность внимание.

[http://непроявленный-мир.рф/323-kto-takie-trolli.html](http://%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80.%D1%80%D1%84/323-kto-takie-trolli.html)

https://unotices.com/page-answer.php?id=4985

Как я полагаю, тролля изначально **можно не заметить**, но потом он всё-таки вычисляется по тому упорству, с которым проводит свою политику. Тролли могут представлять **опасность** для сетевого общества.

2) **Слово происходит от английского trolling,** герундий от  troll ‘ловить на блесну’ ...связь с ловлей на блесну возникла, вероятно, под влиянием англ. trawl ‘трал’ или trail ‘тянуть, волочить’.

И вопрос: **Что общего между ловлей рыбы на блесну и сетевым троллингом?**  Иначе говоря, почему жаргонное слово получило такое название?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что написано в Викисловаре.

Троллинг

**неол.** размещение в Интернете (на форумах, в дискуссионных группах, в вики-проектах, и др.) провокационных сообщений с целью вызвать конфликты между субъектами, взаимные оскорбления и т. п. ◆ **Троллинг на форумах также напоминает рыбалку.** **Наивным юзерам подкидывается провокационный пост (приманка), те эмоционально на него реагируют и тем самым напоминают пойманную рыбёшку в сетях флеймера.** «Паразиты сети», 2010 г. // «Компьютеры, Сети, Программирование».

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на правду.  Но где-то с третьей рыбки-блесны юзеры должны догадаться, что их разыгрывают.

Comment: Они догадываются, но это слабо помогает. Одного грамотного и опытного человека затроллить невозможно, но сообщество таких людей уже можно. Легко понять почему, если понаблюдать хоть раз, но долго описывать словами.

Comment: grizzly прав: грамотного и опытного человека затроллить невозможно. Затроллить можно неопытных пользователей, которые особо не интересуются, так сказать, интернет-миром.

Answer (score 1):

Один вопрос остался без ответа.

> Для чего, к примеру, тролли любят злить людей в сети?

Они могут делать это и неосознанно. Но в любом случае, думаю, что если это не профессиональная деятельность (политика или любого рода оплачиваемая работа), то основная её цель — самовыражение. Обычные "статусные" войны с весьма необычной спецификой удалённого общения. Женщины, кстати, занимаются этим намного реже (да я вообще не припомню, чтобы замечал).

Comment: Если это единичные тролли, то наверное. Но когда появляется  их целый десант  (и у каждого своя рыбка), то начинаешь думать о более значимых целях, о сговоре по крайней мере.

Answer (score 0):

Троллинг  изначально  это был человек далекий от мира ЭВМ , который недавно вошел в сеть и постоянно влазил в беседу опытных пользователей ,бесконно путаясь под ногами ,задавая глупые вопросы ,как? почему ?  Со временем таких новичков стало так много ,что им пришлось дать  классификацию  болтуна и пустобреха.

Comment: А как это связано с английским словом troll "ловить на блесну"? Вопрос был об этом.  И почему Вы считаете, что троллинг сначала обозначал непреднамеренное действие?  Возможно вредоносный умысел был в таком поведении  изначально?

Comment: Trolling (fishing)
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Jump to navigationJump to search
Not to be confused with Trawling.

Comment: Всё ясно, спасибо.